# App menu not showing setup option while booting

Tags: windows-10, bios, ubuntu-18.04

I installed ubuntu 18.04 on a Samsung laptop which made the set up menu missing from the options as show in the picture. Previously it was visible. After that I installed Windows 10 by removing ubuntu and still I am not able to see the bios option.

I tried pressing f2, f10 and escape keys while booking which never worked. In order to boot the system to Windows I have to turn off and on again multiple times. This way sometimes it will boot to an OS.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVEr8.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMCSa.jpg]